# Joomla 3.3.1 category blog not showing on specific template

Tags: templates, joomla, blogs, categories

I'm working on Joomla 3.3.1 (on Mac, MAMP). When I choose to display a menu item as "category blog" it leads to a blank page. If I select a different template style (on the menu item details) the page does show correctly.

How can I use my default template to show the page correctly? Where can the problem be?

I'm using the template "ict_conches_free" as my default template.

Comment: Check `templates/YOU_TEMPLATE/html/com_content/category`. If this exists, take a backup, and removed the `category` folder, then try again. This is a template override and it's quite possible whoever made it has screwed up.

Answer (score 1):

Will just add this as a proper answer:

Try checking for the following directory `templates/YOU_TEMPLATE/html/com_content/category`. If it exists then it mean a Template Override has been made for that specific view which allows users to override the view of an extension without having to modify core files.

In your case, if it exists, then the override is faulty in some way, shape or form. So simply delete the `category` folder.